# even after the execution of the Stored Procedure 'operand should contain one column' is giving error not able to understand

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sample`(IN `feename` VARCHAR(50), IN `feemslno` INT(11))
BEGIN

SELECT id INTO @f FROM s_menu where name='FEES' LIMIT 1; 

INSERT INTO s_menu (name, mslno, parentid,url,roles) 
    SELECT (feename, feemslno, @f,'feeblank.php','All,Notview,sysadmin')
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM s_menu WHERE url='feeblank.php' 
                        AND name='Reports'); 

SELECT id INTO @c FROM s_menu where url='feeblank.php' LIMIT 1; 

UPDATE s_menu SET parentid=@c WHERE url = 'fee_dues_details_with_jTable_ver3.php' 
    AND id!=1;
UPDATE s_menu SET parentid=@c WHERE url = 'fee_dues_summary_with_jTable_ver_3.php' 
    AND id!=1;
UPDATE s_menu SET parentid=@c WHERE url = 'fee_dues_summary_class_section_wise_with_jTable_ver_2.php' 
    AND id!=1;
UPDATE s_menu SET parentid=@c WHERE url = 'fee_dues_summary_school_wide_with_jTable_ver_2.php' 
    AND id!=1;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: None in shown code can produce mentioned error message. I think the problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the brackets in the statemenT `SELECT (feename, feemslno, @f,'feeblank.php','All,Notview,sysadmin')` and I note that there was an unresolved discussion about the use of DUAL in your previous question - I have tried your code and without from dual I get a syntax error.